# Adding an access token to an FQL using the facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

I am making an FQL facebook call via the javascript sdk in the following way:

```
FB.api(
       {
       method: 'fql.query',
       query: 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'
       },
       function(friendData) {
       //Call back code
       }
       );
```

I can't figure out how to include my access token. Can someone help me out with the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

The AcessToken is provided by the function FB.login, where you define the permissions that you need, and then, the user accepts it, generating an AcessToken. So, after that, you can make your Graph request

Comment: I have successfully generated my access token. My issue is that I can't figure out how to send it along with my FQL request.

Comment: If you have generated the acesstoken via FB.login, it goes automatically, there is no need to set it.

Could you publish your code here for a better insight.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
FB.api(
       {
       method: 'fql.query',
       query: 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()',
       access_token:accessToken
       },
       function(friendData) {
       //callback code
       }
    );
```